# ZF1 Doctrine2 Service Layer

Tags: php, zend-framework, design-patterns, doctrine-orm

I'm looking for a good example of how to correctly implement Service Layer with Zend Framework and Doctrine2

I've seen some implementations but all of them have access to the EM from the controller when instantiating the service, and I think that might be wrong or not?

Exmaple:
http://cobbweb.me/2010/11/integrate-doctrine-2-zend-framework-application/

Also I got to [this project](https://github.com/guilhermeblanco/ZF1-Doctrine2-ServiceLayer) but not really sure how to implement it:

Thanks

Comment: It's not "wrong" really. It's mostly whether you want or need to make your architecture more complex by introducing something else which is used instead of the EM (eg. service locator, factory, etc.)

Comment: @JaniHartikainen hmm you probably talk about zf2.The example link is good starting point, i used it before. All i can say is head to github and download some couple repositories. Chekout these guyz #dynamicguy #luxemate #szjani #cobbweb and ...

Answer (score 1):

Use a helper to act like a factory for the services:

- You need to create an Action Helper and inject the EntityManager on it when you register the instance in the Front Controller.
- This Action Helper receives as parameter in the `direct()` method the name of the service class that the factory should create.

  - Inside this method you should try to instantiate the service class requested, and return it (or throw an exception if the same is not found).
- Let your service classes receive as parameter in the constructor the EntityManager and inject it during the construction on the factory.

The rest should already be clear to you. In your controller you only need to use something like:

```php
SomeController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    //...
    public function someAction ()
    {
        $myService = $this->_helper->service( 'MyService' );
        $myService->doSomething();
    }
 }
```